# get folder size in a function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to obtain the size of each folder and **its sub-folders** along with the owner, path, and last modified date - also up to a depth of 5. **I have everything except for the size of the folder completed**  I am trying to get the size in MB

Here is the code I have:

```
Function Get-Depth {
    Param(
        [String]$Path = '/Users/demo/main',
        [String]$Filter = "*",
        [Int]$ToDepth = 4,
        [Int]$CurrentDepth = 0
    )
    #incrimintation
    $CurrentDepth++

 #obtains the path and passes the filter values. KEEP in mind that level 1 is 0.
    Get-ChildItem $Path | %{
        $_ | ?{ $_.Name -Like $Filter }
 #if thier is a folder, use the depth and run function until to depth value is 4
         If ($_.PsIsContainer) {
         If ($CurrentDepth -le $ToDepth) {

         # Call to function
         #adds the filter values and depth to the path..
         Get-Depth -Path $_.FullName -Filter $Filter `
          -ToDepth $ToDepth -CurrentDepth $CurrentDepth
        }
     }
   }

}


#just calling the function and and adding what we want!

Get-Depth|? {$_.PsIsContainer}| select @{Name='Date Modified'; 
Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},
@{Name='Owner'; E={(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}}, 
Fullname
```

Structure I am trying to obtain

```
 h:\demo\1st level
 h:\demo\1st level\2nd level
 h:\demo\1st level\2nd level\3rd level
 h:\demo\1st level\2nd level\3rd level\4th level\
 h:\demo\1st level\2nd level\3rd level\4th level\5th level
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would avoid reinventing the wheel and just use [`du.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/du.aspx).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Thank you, but is there anyway to work my way around using this? I am trying to obtain very specific parameters.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
(Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -directory -Recurse  | %{

$charCount = ($_.Fullname.ToCharArray() | Where {$_ -eq '\'} | Measure-Object).Count

if ($charCount -gt 5) { continue}

$size=(Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname -file -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).Sum

[pscustomobject]@{
'Date Modified'=$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')

Owner=$_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\')[1]
Fullname=$_.Fullname
Size= if ($size) {[Math]::Round($size / 1MB,2,[MidPointRounding]::AwayFromZero)       } else {0}
LevelDir=$charCount
}

}) | sort Fullname, LevelDir
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't get the size in MB and does not adhere to depth of 5. I am also trying to get the size of all the subfolders

Comment: try my modification ;)

Comment: for some reason its not appearing in a file tree format, see updated question.

Comment: I am still not able to achieve the file path specified in the question. thanks